# Using latest role ARN in a separate scheduler cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, scheduled-tasks

We're using cloudformation for managing out AWS deployments. The deployment consists of a main monolith service, with many environment variables, in on cloudformation file.

We'd like to add a scheduler, managed in a different cloudformation stack, which runs the same service, with the same environment variables, but parameterized to run a specific script using containerOverrides:

```
Type: AWS::Scheduler::Schedule
Properties:
  [...]
  Target:
    [..]
    RoleArn: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/app-${EnvName}-${AppServiceName}-task-role"
```

^^ the issue is the RoleArn. Per documentation, this will be deployed using the latest Role *at the time the scheduler is deployed*.

However, when the environment variables in the main task changes (stored in the role), we want the scheduler to use those, ie: always use the latest version of the role ARN.

We've tried: RoleArn: [...]:latest to no avail.

How to make this cloudformation script always use the latest version of the role arn?

Answer (score 0):

> How to make this cloudformation script always use the latest version of the role arn?

You can't. You have to manually modify your scheduler template to update it to latest role.

Answer (score 0):

Actual answer: TaskDefinitions are versioned, each revision is immutable; and when no version is specified (as above), each scheduled task instantiation will point to the latest version automatically.

On the other hand,  IAM roles are mutable, so if a task role is changed, it gets automatically picked up

- This applies only on next execution -ie if there is a cronjob running, and config changes are made, the currently running cronjob will finish executing with the same privileges, and taskdefinition